# Which API operation is used for uploading a custom ontology to an Azure Digital Twins instance?

Tags: azure-digital-twins

In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/concepts-objectmodel-spatialgraph) there's a paragraph about Graph extensibility that reads:

> Use extensibility to customize the underlying Digital Twins object models with new types and ontologies. Your Digital Twins data also can be enriched with extensible properties and values.

I found operations in the [Digital Twins Service Management API](https://docs.westcentralus.azuresmartspaces.net/management/swagger/docs/V1) for Listing, Retrieving and Update status for the preloaded ontologies but not for uploading a new custom one.

If I try to create/upload a new Ontology using the [Update](https://docs.westcentralus.azuresmartspaces.net/management/swagger/ui/index#/operations/Ontologies/Ontologies_Update) operation I receive a error result:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "404.600.000.001",
        "message": "Specified Ontology was not found."
    }
}
```

Is it possible to upload new ontologies in the public preview and if so, what API operation should I use to upload my custom ontology to my Digital Twins instance?

Thanks!

Comment: Extended Types and Properties provide a degree of customization built into the preview spec. You can add or enrich the top-level data types using them. There are several hundred existing Types and Properties supplied out of the box.

Comment: These are distinct from the ability to modify the core Ontology itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the paragraph about Ontologies in the swagger [documentation](https://docs.westcentralus.azuresmartspaces.net/management/swagger/ui/index#) i found the following:

> Ontologies are managed by the system and new ontologies or new type names are regularly added. Users can load or unload ontologies.

I understand now that this means **it is not possible to add a custom ontology**, only load or unload the ones already provided by the system.

Comment: Ontologies can be viewed essentially as extended types, thus you might be able to add your own extended types to then achieve what you're looking for, and we will add this to our feature request list

Answer (score 1):

For public preview release you cannot author and upload your own ontology. This feature is possible currently only with our support. You need to contact us, we’ll provide you with a schema and we’ll upload it for you. However, this will change in GA. We’ll create a library of ontologies having a public schema and we reserve the right to certify the authors. After certification, we’ll import the ontologies into the platform. It’s our goal to expose publicly standardized ontologies and not end up with thousands of flavors of these. However, I understand that some users might want to import new ontologies, without making them public. This is something we are considering as well.